# C macro - Returning a pointer or assigning a value to a pointer passed to the macro

Tags: c, object, pointers, macros

I'm trying to write "object" style C code because I need to declare the same object several times with different parameters. Everything works fine except for returning or assigning a pointer to the created object. I've searched and found couple examples but none of them are working.

Here is what is working.

Header file:

```
#ifndef _OBJECT_H_
#define _OBJECT_H_

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t* Buffer_PU8;
    uint8_t Index_U8;
}TParameters_S;

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t ID_U8;
    TParameters_S* Parameters_PS;
}TObject_S;

#define NEW_OBJECT(id, size) \
    static uint8_t Buffer_AU8##id[size]; \
    static TParameters_S Parameters_S##id = { \
        0, Buffer_AU8##id \
    }; \
    static const TObject_S __attribute__((used, section("my_objects"))) Object_S##id = { \
        id, &Parameters_S##id \
    }; \

#endif  // _OBJECT_H_
```

Source file:

```
#incldue "object.h"

typedef enum
{
    OBJECT1_E,
    OBJECT2_E,
}TObjects_E;

NEW_OBJECT(OBJECT1_E, 10);
NEW_OBJECT(OBJECT2_E, 20);

void function(void)
{
}
```

This works fine and creates two "objects" in the section "my_objects". Each object having a different sized buffer.

But I would like to get a pointer to the object so that I can operate on it. I can search for the objects in the "my_objects" section and point to that, but it would be great if I can assign a pointer to the object at compile time. Then I do not have to waste time or code space to search for the object.

So I've tried this but it does not work (Hoping it would assign a object pointer to "handle"):

Header file:

```
#define NEW_OBJECT(id, size, handle) \
    static uint8_t Buffer_AU8##id[size]; \
    static TParameters_S Parameters_S##id = { \
        0, Buffer_AU8##id \
    }; \
    static const TObject_S __attribute__((used, section("my_objects"))) Object_S##id = { \
        id, &Parameters_S##id \
    }; \
    handle = &Object_S##id; \ <----- This does not work
```

Source file:

```
TObject_S* object1_PS;
TObject_S* object1_PS;

// therefore does not work
NEW_OBJECT(OBJECT1_E, 10, object1_PS);
NEW_OBJECT(OBJECT2_E, 20, object2_PS);

void function(void)
{
    // Then operate on the object (and therefore this does not work)
    object1_PS->Parameters_PS->Buffer_PS[object1_PS->Parameters_PS->Index_U8];
}
```

I've also tried this, hoping it would return a pointer to the object (I think I'm taking a chance here):

Header file:

```
#define NEW_OBJECT(id, size) \
    static uint8_t Buffer_AU8##id[size]; \
    static TParameters_S Parameters_S##id = { \
        0, Buffer_AU8##id \
    }; \
    static const TObject_S __attribute__((used, section("my_objects"))) Object_S##id = { \
        id, &Parameters_S##id \
    }; \
    &Object_S##id; \ <----- This does not work
```

Source file:

```
// therefore this does not work
TObject_S* object1_PS = NEW_OBJECT(OBJECT1_E, 10, object1_PS);
TObject_S* object1_PS = NEW_OBJECT(OBJECT2_E, 20, object2_PS);

void function(void)
{
    // Then operate on the object (and therefore this does not work)
    object1_PS->Parameters_PS->Buffer_PS[object1_PS->Parameters_PS->Index_U8];
}
```

This works, but I think it is creating two pointers for each object. Although I can only see one pointer for each object in the map file:

Header file:

```
#define NEW_OBJECT(id, size, handle) \
    static uint8_t Buffer_AU8##id[size]; \
    static TParameters_S Parameters_S##id = { \
        0, Buffer_AU8##id \
    }; \
    static const TObject_S __attribute__((used, section("my_objects"))) Object_S##id = { \
        id, &Parameters_S##id \
    }; \
    static const TObject_S* __attribute__((used, section("my_objects_pointers"))) handle = &Object_S##id; \ <----- This works
```

Source file:

```
TObject_S* object1_PS;
TObject_S* object1_PS;

// therefore this works
NEW_OBJECT(OBJECT1_E, 10, object1_PS);
NEW_OBJECT(OBJECT2_E, 20, object2_PS);

void function(void)
{
    // Then operate on the object (and therefore this works)
    object1_PS->Parameters_PS->Buffer_PS[object1_PS->Parameters_PS->Index_U8];
}
```

Comment: " it would be great if I can assign a pointer to the object at compile time"  - I don't think you really want to do this. Do you have that type of control over the memory management of your environment?

Comment: Why not? Everytime I call NEW_OBJECT, the compiler will create a single instance of the struct TObject and the linker will place it in the section "my_objects". Now I just want a variable pointing to that object. It is like any other variable pointing to a structure. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Just a heads-up, `#define _OBJECT_H_` is illegal.  Identifiers beginning with an underscore and a capital letter are reserved in all contexts.

Comment: Why not use `&Object_SOBJECT1_E` directly as the pointer to the object?

Comment: "the compiler will create a single instance of the struct" -- No, it won't.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think I've tried that. In theory it should work. I will give another try. Would still be "nice" if the macro can assign a pointer or return a pointer.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler for the last method you showed? You are defining the same variable twice with different declarations.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya That is what I said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executable statements, such as assignment statements, must appear inside functions.  This is the main reason why the

```
    handle = &Object_S##id; \ <----- This does not work
```

does not work (in your particular usage).  But you can *initialize* variables in (at most) one of their declarations.  For example, then:

```
#define NEW_OBJECT(id, size, handle) \
    static uint8_t Buffer_AU8##id[size]; \
    static TParameters_S Parameters_S##id = { \
        Buffer_AU8##id, 0 \
    }; \
    static const TObject_S __attribute__((used, section("my_objects"))) Object_S##id = { \
        id, &Parameters_S##id \
    }; \
    const TObject_S *handle = &Object_S##id;


const TObject_S *object1_PS;  // This is redundant and can be dropped

NEW_OBJECT(OBJECT1_E, 10, object1_PS);
```

Note that since you're declaring the structure itself as `const`, the pointer to it needs to accommodate that.  Note also that I've flipped the order of the element initializers for the `struct TParameters_S` to match the intent that seems apparent from the structure definition.

**Addendum:**

Note also that unless you actually want separate variables for the buffer and parameters then, given that you're declaring everything at file scope, you could substitute compound literals to achieve a cleaner namespace:

```
#define NEW_OBJECT(id, size, handle) \
    static const TObject_S __attribute__((used, section("my_objects"))) Object_S##id = { \
        .ID_U8 = id, .Parameters_PS = & (TParameters_S) { \
            .Buffer_PU8 = (uint8_t[]) { [size - 1] = 0 }, .Index_U8 = 0 } \
    }; \
    const TObject_S *handle = &Object_S##id;
```

You could take that one step further to eliminate the `Object_S*`variables, leaving just the handle pointers as declared variables, but I don't know that you can apply attributes to compound literals.

Comment: Is the `const TObject_S *object1_PS;` before `NEW_OBJECT...` just redundant or infact wrong? Aren't those different definitions of the same variable?

Comment: No, @AjayBrahmakshatriya, they are not.  Multiple *declarations* of the same variable are allowed, provided the types are compatible, at most one declaration has an initializer, and a couple other requirements about the declared linkage are satisfied (including that the variable *have* linkage).

Comment: @JohnBollinger About your addendum, wouldn't that set parameters and its members to const? Since the object is const? I explicitly declare them like that so that they are not const.

Comment: @user668773, the compound literal alternative does not make anything `const` that was not already `const`.  Compound literals represent modifiable objects (unlike string literals), so either way, what is `const` is the object id and *the pointer to* the parameters.  The parameters themselves are modifiable -- index, buffer pointer, and buffer elements.  Note also that whereas the handle points to a `const` structure, it itself (the pointer) is modifiable.

Comment: I am pretty sure bells are ringing in many chat rooms because of that word!

Comment: Perhaps it's just my hubris, @AjayBrahmakshatriya, but from context and tone I took it as a complement.  I think they meant that they think I'm so knowledgeable in this area that I must be stupid about other things to balance out.  (But perhaps I should be offended that they discount the possibility of me being an all-around genius?  :-) )

Comment: @user668773 it's not at all odd to find all-around geniuses here :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, with the comments above (Henning and Ajay) I managed to come up with a solution.

The problem is that the object requires a constant initilizer element. So I can't assign a variable to a variable in that scope. But I can overcome it with a macro. So what I have done is this:

Header file:

```
#define NEW_OBJECT(id, size) \
    static uint8_t Buffer_AU8##id[size]; \
    static TParameters_S Parameters_S##id = { \
        0, Buffer_AU8##id \
    }; \
    static const TObject_S __attribute__((used, section("my_objects"))) id = { \
        &Parameters_S##id \
    }; \

#define GET_OBJECT(id) (TObject_S*)&id
```

Source file:

```
NEW_OBJECT(OBJECT1, 10);

const TObject_S* object1_PS = (TObject_S*)GET_OBJECT(OBJECT1);

void function(void)
{
    object1_PS->Parameters_PS->Buffer_PS[object1_PS->Parameters_PS->Index_U8];
}
```

All the casting might not be necessary but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are writing assignments at global scope. When `NEW_OBJECT` expands it creates -

`handle = &Object_S0;`

for the first object. This is not allowed in C.

You will have to move this assignment inside the main function or use `&Object_S0` wherever you need to reference it.

You can create the object inside a function and it would be fine. The object would be created statically and the assignment would happen at runtime.

Comment: Yes, it requires a constant initializer element.And assigning a variable to a variable in the global scope is not allowed. But I could overcome it with another macro?

Comment: You can move the declaration of the variable inside the macro too. Basically what you did in the last method in your question and then remove the extra declaration you have for the pointer.